How do I export history from Google Podcasts?
Google Podcasts will be discontinued soon. There is a way to export subscriptions, but I couldn't find more. 
I'd really like to export the history of what I've already listened to, and hopefully my queue too. How can it be done?

As Google just doesn't seem to care I wrote this little script to export my Google Podcasts listening history: https://gist.github.com/tadwohlrapp/73864c03734a14a9d27cc15e4fa142ba
You can run it in the browser console or as a bookmarklet using a bookmarklet generator like https://caiorss.github.io/bookmarklet-maker/

Is there a use case for the exported format please? At best another podcasts app able to import it?

Per @romanzdk's SO answer to "How can Google Podcasts data be exported/accessed?", you can get the information using Google Takeout:

The only way to download playback history from Google Podcasts I found is to use Google Takeout (this link can be found in the "More options" section of the My Activity — Podcasts page, where you can also see your subscriptions).
If you click the "All activity data included" button, you'll be able to specify which Google app you want to export data form. Click the "Deselect all" option to remove all apps, then check only the Podcasts entry.
You can also select the "Multiple formats" button to pick what format you want for your data export: HTML or JSON files (the default is HTML). The information in the files includes the activity type (playbacks, searches, etc.) and the corresponding date.


thanks! I've tried it, unfortunately it contains only the channel name of the podcasts I've listened to, but not the episodes.
